# C - Using a char pointer to print int value, not getting expected result

Tags: c, pointers, memory, char, integer

I'm trying to understand how pointers work. I created an `int` value and made a `char` pointer to point at it.

When printing the content of the address that `char` pointer points to, I don't get the expected result.

Like if that `char` pointer is pointing to **256**, I was expecting the content of that address to return **0** because **(256)10 = (0000000100000000)2**. Because a `char` pointer points to one byte so it'll return the first 8 bits which are zeros.

But it returns **-1**.

Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int y = 256;
    char *p = (char *)&y;

    // returns Value -1
    printf("Value %d \n", *p);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps because the anti-aliasing rule is broken which lead to UB?  The value in `y` is not known to be used and so it is optimized out?

Comment: That's curious.  What machine are you running on?  O/S?  Compiler?  It could be partly an 'endianness' issue, but superficially, you should be getting a zero whether it is big-endian or little-endian.  When I test the code on both RHEL 5 and Mac OS X 10.11.1, I get 0 output, as I'd expect.

Comment: @chux: Aren't `char *` exempt from anti-aliasing?  (And I think we both mean 'strict aliasing' — anti-aliasing is related to things like fonts and pixels, isn't it?)

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler  I think you are correct.

Comment: @chux Any object can be accessed through a character pointer without violating strict-aliasing. It's not UB.

Comment: @Rafael Are you sure you got -1 as output for 256, not 255?

Comment: @Blue Moon Does the anti-aliasing rule exemption to `char *`, `unsigned char *`, etc?

Comment: That's weird `p = &y` caused the problem, but `p = (char *)&y` didn't. I'm curious why though. And also shouldn't `255` returns 255 as well ?

Comment: @chux Yes. There's another type to that list: `signed char*`. C standard considers the 3 of them as distinct types.

Comment: What do you get with `printf("Value %d %d\n", *p, y);`?

Comment: @chux for y = 256, I get "Value 0 256". But for y = 255, I get "Value -1 255"

Comment: This differs from your original post that had `y=256` and "it returns -1".  Now the answer is easy. code is simply printing the least significant byte of `y` as a `signed char`.

Comment: @chux Sorry, but what do you mean by "The original case could be explained by `y` being optimized out as it was not used."

Comment: When code explicitly uses `y` as in `printf("Value %d %d\n", *p, y);`, then `y` is used and must have the _value_ of 255 or 256 or whatever.  Without using `y`, but only the _address_ of `y` as in `char *p = (char *)&y` it is unclear to me  if a compliant compiler must maintain the value of `y`.  It that were the case, possible the compiler did not initialize `y` as thought.

Comment: @chux But why 255 still gives me -1 ? Even though i'm printing `y`

Comment: Getting `Value -1 255` when `y` is 255 makes sense.  `p` points to a byte that looks like `11111111` in binary, `*p` is a signed char, and `%d` prints a signed value, so that's why it prints -1.

Comment: @dbush Ah, I totally forgot about the MSB. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> But why 255 still gives me -1 ? Even though i'm printing
>   `y`

Getting `Value -1 255` when `y` is 255 makes sense.  `p` points to a byte that looks like `11111111` in binary, `*p` is a signed char, and `%d` prints a signed value, so that's why it prints -1.
                    – dbush